# Why is this function well-behaved?

Tags: functions

Why is this function $f(x) = \dfrac{\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})}{\pi(1-x^2)}$ well behaved at $x=\pm 1$? 
I thought it would have an asymptote at $x=\pm 1$ due to the denominator, but apparently its value at $x=\pm  1$ is $\frac{1}{4}$. Why is that so?

Comment: It's not defined at $\pm 1$. What *is* true is that $\lim_{x \to \pm 1} f(x)$ exists and is finite, because $\cos(\pm \pi/2) = 0$.

Comment: What's your definition of "well behaved"? You are absolutely correct that the function is undefined on $x = \pm 1$.  But that doesn't mean it has an asymptote there.  In this case it has a removable singularity and the limits as x tends to $\pm 1$ exist and are $\pm 1/4$.  I suppose that is "well-behaved".  But you are correct.  The function doesn't exist at that point.   There is simply a "hole" at those points and the function is well behaved (bounded, continuous, etc.) near these "holes".

Comment: It is very important *not* to say the value at x= +/- is 1/4.  The values *AREN"T* +/- 1/4.  The function *is* undefined at those points as you suspected.  So whoever told you the function *was* 1/4 at those points was incorrect or you misunderstood what they meant.  I'm not entirely sure what "well-behaved" should mean but... having removable singularities isn't an unreasonable characteristic, I guess.

Comment: According to this source http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParticularlyWell-BehavedFunctions.html "well-behaved" means the derivatives exist at all points which is the case of this function (a derivative is a limit so the function needn't actually be defined at a point for its derivative to be defined--- I think).  However other source say other things.

Comment: Ahh thank you! So am I correct to say that being continuous or defined is not necessary for the function to be well-behaved?

Comment: It would be more correct to say that $f(x)$ has removable discontinuities at $x=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The denominator of $\dfrac x x$ at $x=0$ is $0$, but that doesn't mean there is a vertical asymptote there.  Notice that $\dfrac x x$ remains equal to $1$ as $x$ approaches $0$.  The fraction $\dfrac 5 x$ has a vertical asymptote because when $x$ is near $0$ then $x$ goes into $5$ a very very large number of times.

In the case of $f(x) = \dfrac{\cos(\frac{\pi x} 2)}{\pi(1-x^2)}$, the numerator and denominator both approach $0$ as $x\to\pm1$.  Therefore this is like $x/x$ rather than like $5/x$.

L'Hopital's rule will get you the limit without much effort and also without much insight.

$$
f(x) = \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})}{\pi(1-x^2)} = \frac 1 {1+x} \cdot \frac 1 \pi\cdot  \frac{\cos(\frac\pi 2 x)}{1-x} = \frac 2 {1+x} \cdot  \frac{\sin(\frac\pi2(1-x))}{\frac \pi 2(1-x)} = \frac 2 {1+x} \cdot \frac{\sin u} u.
$$
Then we have $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u} u$, which you have probably seen done by squeezing.

Answer (score 1):

Although $f$ is not yet defined at $\pm 1$, after writing

$$f(x) = -\frac{1}{\pi(1 + x)} \frac{\cos(\pi x / 2)}{x - 1}$$

one can recognize that

$$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = -\frac{1}{2\pi} \left.\frac{d}{dx} \right|_{x = 1} \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\pi}{2} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \frac 1 4$$

As such, we can extend $f$ to be defined and continuous at $1$ by assigning its value there to be $\frac 1 4$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, that looks a lot nicer.